# Checked boxes on one page are carrying over to a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a site for work.

It consists of four pages which are the exact same structure but different content.

The structure is `three columns`, the first is a vertical `series of check boxes`, the second is a `logo`, the third is another vertical `series of check boxes`.

The `goal` is to,

1. Be able to go to page one, click the check boxes needed, and keep those boxes checked upon refresh.
2. Then you should be able to click a link to the second page and have a fresh set of check boxes.

The content is there, the links are there, all of the check boxes are there and remain upon refresh.

The problem I'm having is that when I check a few boxes on page one and then click on the link to page two, the `same check boxes` are still checked, even though it's an entirely new page and new content.

I tried linking each of the four pages to their own `JavaScript` file and that didn't change anything. I am new to developing and am not sure what to try next.

Here is the JavaScript code I am using:

```
jQuery(function(){
    if (localStorage.input) {
        var checks = JSON.parse(localStorage.input);
        jQuery(':checkbox').prop('checked', function(i) {
            return checks[i];
        });
    }
});

jQuery(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.input = JSON.stringify(jQuery(':checkbox').map(function() {
        return this.checked;
    }).get());
});
```

This works great if it's a one page site but again, when I visit one of the other pages, the check boxes don't refresh.

If anyone can, please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the checkbox information in `input` on `localStorage` for every page. The data is just an array of `true`/`false` values indicating whether or not the checkboxes on a page are checked.

If you run this code on another page which has checkboxes then they'll be put into that state.

You need to store the information in a way that identifies which page it's on, e.g.

```
localStorage[window.location.href] = ...
```

Or

```
localStorage.setItem(window.location.href, ...)
```

You could also store the state of the checkboxes against their names/ids to avoid coupling the state to the order of the boxes on the page e.g.

```
let state = {
  'choice0': true,
  'choice1': false,
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I would be changing. Am I changing all instances of "localStorage.input" to "localStorage[window.location.href]"? If that's all I'm changing, what do I use as the href since it needs to be able to check the page it's on and that will change? Do I need to use "else if" statements for each page?

Forgive me. I have wrapped my head around HTML and CSS but JavaScript is giving me more of a challenge.

Comment: Yes, you should just be able to change `localStorage.input` to `localStorage[window.location.href]`. The value of `window.location.href` will change on each page you're on - and that's exactly the point. Each page should store its checkbox state in its own space on `localStorage` and retrieve it using its own identifier - I've chosen the URL of the page to ensure that it'll be different on each page. Try it.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!